# CSS3 - Possible Chrome browser bug with CSS animation?

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, bounce

I have a label and want to let it bounce using CSS3 animation. This works in all **latest** browsers like a charm.

However, once I add a `display:inline` to the label, the bounce animation effect doesn't work on Chrome browser. It does work for every other browser like IE11, Firefox and Opera, but for some reason it does not work for the latest Chrome browser. Is this a Chrome bug or is there a good explanation for it?

Here is a test case: https://jsfiddle.net/fuex3nz1/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS transfroms does not works on inline level elements(I mean only display: inline and label is by default inline level). You can use

```
.label {display:inline-block;}
```

For more info about CSS transforms property check it
https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#terminology

And for inline-level elements check this http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/inline.html

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So actually not Chrome but the other browsers are wrong about how they deal with inlined animations?

Comment: CSS transforms with a inline level element will ignore by the browser. And I check your code also in Microsoft Edge and Mozilla and none of this work label with display: inline but every browser work with display: inline-block . But in your case why other browser works I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for the help!